# How can I shorten this Python script for copying a file into another file?

Tags: python

Python newbie here. Just starting to learn. I am following "How to Learn Python the Hard Way" and one of the exercises is to shorten a script as much as we can. I have hit a sort of road block and I'd appreciate any insight. The code simply takes a file and copies it into another file. This is what the code looked like at first.

```
from sys import argv
from os.path import exists

script, from_file, to_file = argv

print "Copying from %s to %s" % (from_file, to_file)

in_file = open(from_file)
indata = in_file.read()

print "The input file is %d bytes long" % len(indata)

print "Does the output file exist? %r" % exists(to_file)
print "Ready, hit RETURN to continue, CTRL-C to abort."
raw_input()

out_file = open(to_file, 'w')
out_file.write(indata)

print "Alright, all done."

out_file.close()
in_file.close()
```

Now the code looks like this:

```
 from sys import argv; script, from_file, to_file = argv; 

 in_data = open(from_file).read()

 out_file = open(to_file, 'w').write(in_data)
```

Is it cheating to use a semicolon as a way to keep two lines as one line? I got rid of some of the features because I felt like they were pointless for this particular exercise. The author said he was able to get the script down to one line and I would appreciate any suggestions for how to do this. The script works this way and I've tried fitting it all onto one or two lines with semicolons but I was wondering if there's a better solution. Thanks very much.

Comment: Try, `open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())`. It makes one liner. But for copying files you should use shutil.copyfile as the answer bellow.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `shutil.copyfile` or `shutil.copyfileobj`.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html

BTW:

The purpose of shortening your code is usually to make it easier to understand. While using semicolons to merge several statements in one line doesn't count as cheating, it makes your code less readable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there anything else that can be done to the second code block, though? Or would I need to use shutil.copyfile to get something shorter than what I currently have?

And I'll definitely keep readability in mind. To be honest, I didn't like using the semicolon because it did make it feel harder to read and I can see how it could get hairy fast. If  those 4 lines of code cannot be shortened without using something else like shutil.copyfile, then I think I shall move on to the next exercise. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: I think the way your code is more like a DIY version of `shutil.copyfile`. So the abstract level is different here, what you are trying to do is "read from one file, write to another" plus some complexity imposed on by `Python`, and your code read more or less the same, so IMOP there's not too much space for one to shorten it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one-liner, I suppose:

```
open('outfile','w').write(open('infile').read())
```

This makes me cringe to write code like this.  In fact, don't ever have bare `open` file handles, use `open` as a context manager:

```
with open('infile') as r, open('outfile','w') as w:
    #do things to r and w here
```

It's both compact and good coding practice.

re: semicolons.  Beautiful is better than ugly.  Avoid them at all cost, unless you're contributing to some [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
from sys import argv;
script, from_file, to_file = argv;
open(to_file, 'w').write(open(from_file).read())
```

I am also learning this book as a code beginner.